# findOneAndUpdate doesn't update object - Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to find an item in a collection using its `username` property, then update the `picture_url` property of that item.

I'm using Mongoose, and tried to do this using `findOneAndUpdate` in an async function:

```
const username = 'myusername'
const newPictureLink = 'picture.jpg'
const updatedUser = await UserModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  { username },
  { $set: { picture_url: newPictureLink } },
  { new: true }
)
console.log(updatedUser)
```

But the logged value is the existing item, it's not updated. It's not a logging problem since the item didn't change in the database either.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are not executing the query.
try

```
const updatedUser = await UserModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  { username },
  { $set: { picture_url: newPictureLink } },
  { new: true }
).exec()
```

One more thing, you need to wrap the await call in async function.

Comment: What do you get after this

Comment: I'm using an async function already. The changes you're suggesting don't seem to make a difference

Answer (score 0):

**Before:**

```
{ "username": "foo", "picture_url": "xyz.jpg"}
```

**Query:**

```
let username = "foo";

async function findUpdate(){
  const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { username },
      { picture_url : "kkk.jpg" }, 
      {new: true});

    console.log("updatedUser: ", updatedUser);
}

findUpdate();
```

**After:**

```
updatedUser:  { _id: 5bd89f55f255307d51f32572,
  username: 'foo',
  picture_url: 'kkk.jpg'}
```

**Schema:**

```
let UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String
  },
  picture_url: {
    type: String
  }
});
```

---

**Points to consider:**

- Double check `picture_url` key. You may have spell mistake in the
  schema or in the query.
- Write an `async` function to use `await`.
- Double check `username` key. You may have spell mistake in the schema or in the query.
- No need to write `.exec()` function otherwise you will never have even
  old data under `updatedUser` if function not invoked. Though it is ok
  to write.

Hope this may help you!!!

Comment: Cheers, I'm trying this out. Did you remove the `$set` on purpose? You don't mention it.
About the `exec()`, I just read from the doc: "If you need a fully-fledged promise, use the .exec() function". Since I'm using async / await, do I not need a real promise?

Comment: FindOneAndUpdate designed in this a way that it consider firat parameters as query and second as update. So you don't need to write $set and if you are using $set it is fine too.

You are using async/await so I think you don't need to use any promise then.

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 problems:
first using await function without async, according to DOCS you can't use await without async:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await
2nd: the output that returns from findOneAndUpdate will not promise, will be data that updated, and await can handle promise only.

Comment: The code I entered is already part of an async function, I should have made that clearer.
What are your suggestions to fix the 2nd issue? Prepend with `.exec()`?